# Manifold 2 activation failier

Tags: package, ros, launch, dji-sdk, manifold

when i try to launch dji_sdk sdk.launch i get this error

```
dji@manifold2:~/Desktop/M210_ws$ roslaunch dji_sdk sdk.launch 
... logging to /home/dji/.ros/log/b1f94636-ef16-11e9-bd30-74da38ebc18f/roslaunch-manifold2-6454.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://manifold2:42235/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /dji_sdk/align_time: False
 * /dji_sdk/app_id: 1079440
 * /dji_sdk/app_version: 1
 * /dji_sdk/baud_rate: 115200
 * /dji_sdk/enc_key: 39d353a8e9ad01b6c...
 * /dji_sdk/serial_name: /dev/ttyTHS0
 * /dji_sdk/use_broadcast: False
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.13

NODES
  /
    dji_sdk (dji_sdk/dji_sdk_node)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [6464]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to b1f94636-ef16-11e9-bd30-74da38ebc18f
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6477]
started core service [/rosout]
process[dji_sdk-2]: started with pid [6487]

STATUS/1 @ init, L56: Attempting to open device /dev/ttyTHS0 with baudrate 115200...

ERRORLOG/1 @ _serialOpen, L181: cannot open device /dev/ttyTHS0

ERRORLOG/1 @ init, L61: ...Failed to start serial

ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L423: Port closed.
ERRORLOG/1 @ sendData, L427: Open Protocol cmd send failed, send_len: -1 packet_len: 19

ERRORLOG/1 @ getDroneVersion, L1503: Drone version not obtained! Please do not proceed.
Possible reasons:
    Serial port connection:
        * SDK is not enabled, please check DJI Assistant2 -> SDK -> [v] Enable API Control.
        * Baudrate is not correct, please double-check from DJI Assistant2 -> SDK -> baudrate.
        * TX and RX pins are inverted.
        * Serial port is occupied by another program.
        * Permission required. Please do 'sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER' (you do not need to replace $USER with your username). Then logout and login again

ERRORLOG/1 @ activate, L1387: Unable to initialize some vehicle components![ERROR] [1571121642.979869864]: drone activation error
[ERROR] [1571121642.980001324]: Vehicle initialization failed
```

so now what shold i use for the connection since i'm using manifold 2c which only have UART0 and N/A, it is recomended to use USB-TTL but what baud rate and serial name should i put?

Answer (score 0):

You should use USB-TTL for manifold2-c and choose 921600 buadrate. [link](https://djisdksupport.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025067994-USB-to-TTL-serial-port-module-evaluation-and-recommendation)
The serial name is ttyUSB0,and you can check it in the /dev/

Comment: thank you@bruno , also i have question regarding the connection, if i used USB-TTL cable then there is no need for the 2 type A USB to connect the drone to manifold.??

Comment: You need to use 2 type A USB to connect the drone to the manifold ,if you want to get the video stream of the camera